# It is safe to use "." has MQTT topic level separator instead of "/"?

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, amqp, mqtt, rabbitmq-exchange

The are several devices connected to RabbitMQ using *MQTT* protocol and there are many nodejs process subscribed with *AMPQ* protocol to RabbitMQ to fetch data from those devices.

The devices are publishing with topics structured like this: **data.DEVICETYPE.IDDEVICE**, for example one nodejs process is subscribed on the topic **data.#** for getting ALL messages from devices.

My concern is about the separator that, in this case, is the "."; because in all examples and the documentation of the MQTT protocol, they always use "/" (like a path folder) so i started to think that using the point instead of slash could be a problem.

It's worth to mention that the system actually works well, but i really don't know if in the future this decision could rise compatibly problems.

EDIT: Actually my structure is like this: [RabbitMQ Topic structure](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-javascript.html)
I started from this to create that topic structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/` is the hierarchy separator in MQTT. If you use `.` instead, it "works", but you just have a large number of distinct top level topics.

You couldn't subscribe using wildcards using `data.#` - that is an invalid subscription topic. `#` must be the last character for a subscription and must be on its own level. As `.` is not a hierarchy separator you violate this last rule.

Comment: I modified the question, i hope it helps to understand better the structure and why we choose the "." separator.

Comment: As Roger says, using . means you can't take advantage of the wildcard subscriptions in Topic Filters. The mqtt man page from Mosquitto has a good description of them: http://mosquitto.org/man/mqtt-7.html

Comment: Actually i read that RabbitMQ perform a conversion from "/" to "." . See there https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/rabbitmq-users/mqtt$20amqp$20topic/rabbitmq-users/_WEGGpOrgzs/6DZgWIApM4oJ for matching AMQP filters.